# Here comes the sun auf Deutsch?

Tags: english-to-german, idiomaticity

There's a song sung by a Slovenian band with German lyrics where I don't believe they've got the German quite right. They're wanting to say "Here comes the sun" just like the old Beatles song, and their version is *Hier kommt die Sonne.* Which doesn't sound quite right. Again, German is my second language so I don't have a Fingerspitzengefühl but yeah, it just doesn't sound right. How would a native-German-speaker say "here comes the sun," which is really sort of idiomatic English. I can only come up with awkward things like *schließlich steigt die Sonne auf*. Not quite...

Comment: Are you familiar with [Rammstein](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YtEWoavDlcM&t=1m)?

Comment: I assume the Slovenian band is Laibach: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ix-i4L0PaXI

Comment: Do you possibly mean "Fingerspitzengefühl"? "Spitzengefühl" is a valid word but most probably not what you meant

Comment: There is a version of the Beatles song in Austrian dialect by the band S.T.S.: "do kummt die sunn" . The dialect fits to the melody/meter somewhat better than "da/hier kommt die Sonne" in standard German.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're obviously talking about the song [Vor Sonnen-Aufgang](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ix-i4L0PaXI) by the Slovenian Band Laibach<sup>1</sup>.

The lyrics from this song starts with a quote from the poem [Vor Sonnenaufgang](https://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/book/view/nietzsche_zarathustra03_1884?p=28) by Friedrich Nietsche. This poem is a part of *Also sprach Zarathustra*. The rest of the lyrics seems to be written by Laibach (I'm not absolutely sure about this). But this rest is also written in the style of Nietsches poem.

Except the part *»Hier kommt die Sonne, die Sonne hell«.* This line is not from Nietsche, and its style also doesn't really fit well to the style of the rest of the poem. The poem itself is an ode to the sunrise. In this ode the speaker is talking directly to the sky (the sky in all it's synonymes appears in the grammatical second person), and in this ductus a shoddy simple statement about the advent of the sun doesn't really fit. So, I can understand why you have the feeling, that this doesn't sound right. But it's not a matter of grammar, it's just a matter of style.

This sentence still is an absolutely correct German sentence, and there is even a German cover version of the Beatles-song *»Here comes the sun«* that uses this sentence. - Well, that was not precise enough. The cover-song is not in standard German. It is written in the dialect, that is my real native language: Ost-Steirisch. This is a south-east Bavarian dialect spoken in a region east of Graz in Austria, where I grew up and where the members of the band grew up who wrote the lyrics of this cover version: [Da kummt die Sunn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30brR8dVDYE) by STS.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>»Laibach« used to be the German name of the city that is now known under its Slovenian name »Ljubljana«. Ljubljana is now the capital city of Slovenia, but before 1919 it was part of Austria. In those days Laibach/Ljubljana was the capital city of the Austrian crown land Carniola (German: Krain, Slovenian: Kranjska). And that is why almost all cities in Slovenia have historical German names. And this is also the reason, why there is a German speaking minority in Slovenia. But they don't speak Standard German, They speak Gottscheerisch which is a South-Bavarian dialect with heavy Slovenian influences. I grew up in the South of Austria, where we also speak a South-Bavarian dialect, and Laibach/Ljubljana is only about 130 km away from where I grew up, but Gottscheerisch is almost completely unintelligible to me. Gottscheerisch is a dialect/language that very soon will become distinct. I even don't think that the members of the band Laibach speak Gottscheerisch or any other variation of German, because they make pronunciation errors in their song that are typical for people who don't speak German. The sounds for *ch* (Li**ch**t) and *h* (Rein**h**eit) sound almost identical, the *o* in *Sonnenaufgang* (sunrise, similar to moonrise) is much too long, so that the word sounds like *Sohnenaufgang* (son-rise, similar to daughter-rise), etc.</sub>

Comment: Exactly. Laibach, again playing with crypto-Braun triggers. But it's a beautiful melody. Still, the Hier kommt die Sonne doesn't sound quite Goethe, Eichendorff somehow. Thanks for the deep info.

Answer (score 6):

I know ["Hier kommt die Sonne"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQv7UbY7RXo) as a Rammstein song. Rammstein is an internationally successful German band. You could say they know what they're doing lyrics-wise.

"Hier kommt die Sonne" may have a little bit of a different meaning than "here comes the sun", but it's quite strong, and IMO you could well use it in a German translation of George Harrison's lyrics.

I don't know if you're actually referring to the Rammstein song in your question, but that one is not a translation of the Beatles song. In the Rammstein song, "the sun" seems to actually mean a person.

"Hier kommt XYZ" is an idiom in German, too. It means that XYZ is bursting into the scene, having a strong entrance.

Other songs using it in their title:

> [Hier kommt Alex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6z8o7qAIlIU) - Die Toten Hosen
> [Hier kommt Kurt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrPcg8y2-5E) - Frank Zander
> [Hier kommt die Maus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8nyhA48xP8) - Stefan Raab
> [Klingelingeling, hier kommt der Eiermann](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIsNv0nq0Zs) - Klaus und Klaus

EDIT: I wasn't aware of the [Laibach song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ix-i4L0PaXI) that @Helena linked to in the comments. Reading its lyrics, it seems that it can be interpreted in a metaphorical way, and then the "hier kommt..." wording does make sense. Perhaps it can even be seen as *also* alluding to the Rammstein song, I'm not sure.

Comment: The Beatles' song was about the actual sun and the arrival of spring, e.g. there's the line "it's been a long, cold, lonely winter". So kind of the opposite of Rammstein. Of course there's usually a bit of allegory in song lyrics, good ones at least. I have no idea what the Slovenian band meant by it. I have a feeling that many Rammstein fans are non-German speakers who think German sounds more "metal" than their own language. Tool poked fun at this with "Die Eier von Satan", very "metal" indeed but actually a recipe for cookies.

Comment: I find it very plausible that Laibach have quoted the line from Rammstein, given how these two bands have influenced each other.

Answer (score 2):

To express the "It feels like years since it's been here." in German, I would use

*Die Sonne ist wieder da.*

or

*Die Sonne ist zurück.*

Answer (score 1):

When I read only the title of this question, I thought this would be a question about the song [Da kummt die Sunn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30brR8dVDYE) by Austrian band STS, a cover version of that Beatles song translated into an Austrian dialect.

"Da kummt die Sunn", in standard German, is "Da kommt die Sonne". As "da" und "hier" are fairly similar words, I don't think "hier kommt die Sonne" is a bad wording either.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the song [Gib mir Sonne](https://www.songtexte.com/songtext/rosenstolz/gib-mir-sonne-6bcff632.html) by [Rosenstolz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenstolz) with text lines "Gib mir Sonne", "Wann kommt die Sonne?" and "Hier kommt die Sonne" (although their pronunciation make it sound more like "Hier kommt die Sahne", giving the song quite a different touch...).